# How can I change the system-devices panel icon (the gear icon) without changing the theme?

Tags: icons, panel, icon-themes

The icon I'm talking about is the one on the panel that looks like a gear. Its menu includes a power button, Shut down, Suspend, Logout and all that.

[image]

It's the default icon and to be perfectly frank... I absolutely hate it, but I can't change it without messing with the entire panel (Ubuntu-Mono-dark which I LOVE).

How can you change that icon, and that icon only?

Comment: Hi @KheangHeng if the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you be so kind to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

At least on 16.04 and 16.10, the icon is located:

```
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/system-devices-panel.svg
```

[image]

As you can see, to test, I replaced it with an owncloud icon :)

[image]

#### Notes

1. No need yo say that your new icons need to be of the same type (`.svg`)
2. To edit/replace fioes in `/usr` you need administrator`s permissions. After backing up the old icons, simply run the command (from a terminal):

   ```
   sudo cp /path/to/new/icon.svg  /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/system-devices-panel.svg
   ```
3. You might also want to replace:

   ```
   /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/system-devices-panel-alert.svg
   ```

   and

   ```
   /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/system-devices-panel-information.svg
   ```

   ...to make a matching set in case there would be a change in state for some reason.

Comment: I can't seem to rename/delete or copy files to /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22/. Why is that?

Comment: @KheangHeng Are you using `sudo`? How did you try? In any way, make sure to back ip the original ones!

Comment: Alright I did it, turns out you need to use gksu nautilus in terminal to edit those files. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @KheangHeng *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, would you be so kind to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.